# How to use getter setter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to get the value from `getApi()` but I get `undefined`

My console.log print like:

```
checkAPIDomain 1
checkAPIDomain 2
checkAPIDomain 3 serverUrl 123345
checkAPIDomain 4 apiDomain undefined
```

I suppose it should be `checkAPIDomain 4 serverUrl 123345`

Here is my code:

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

let apiUrl = Config.API_URL; // default API URL

export default class APIDomain {
  constructor() {
    this.apiDomain = null;
  }

  static getApi() {
    console.log('checkAPIDomain 4 apiDomain', this.apiDomain);
    return this.apiDomain;
  }

  checkAPIDomain() {
    console.log('checkAPIDomain 1');
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userServerUrl').then((serverUrl) => {
      console.log('checkAPIDomain 2');
      if (serverUrl !== null && serverUrl !== '') {
        console.log('checkAPIDomain 3 serverUrl', serverUrl);
        this.apiDomain = serverUrl;
      }
      this.apiDomain = apiUrl;
    });
  }
}

APIDomain.shared = new APIDomain();
```

I trigger it in my first file like this:

```
import APIDomain from './src/services/APIDomain';

APIDomain.shared.checkAPIDomain();
```

and get the value from next screen file like this:

```
import APIDomain from './services/APIDomain';

APIDomain.shared.getApi()
```

Did I do anything wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling getApi method to get the value for it? I see you defined getApi, I don't see a call to that method.

Comment: The `getAPI` method is static, so the `this` will reference the class and not the instance - your class does not have an `apiDomain` property (only your instances do)

Comment: Those are not getters nor setters (e.g. `Object.defineProperty`, or `get` and `set` in TypeScript). Those are just normal class member functions.